# I want to change popover content after a click to show cart items. Debug the code

Tags: javascript, django, frontend, bootstrap-5, popover

I want to change popover content after a click to show cart items. Debug the code. The popover is still saying title: "Your Cart" and content: "Hello". I don't know how to fix it. I am currently working on a django project and facing an issue with dynamically changing the content of a popover after a click event. The popover is meant to display the items in the user's shopping cart.

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Forsale</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'shop/style.css' %}>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

body:-

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                            data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <button id="cart-link" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                        data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-trigger="focus"
                                        data-bs-title="Dismissible popover"
                                        data-bs-content="It's very engaging. Right?">
                                        Cart
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link disabled" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form class="card card-sm">
                    <div class="card-body row no-gytters align-items-center">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input class="form-control" type="search" name="item_name"
                                placeholder="Search for Products">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            {% for product in product_objects %}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src={{product.image}} alt="" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div id="prod-name-{{product.id}}" class="card-title">
                            {{product.title}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text">
                            Rs. {{product.price}}
                        </div>

                        <a href={% url 'detail' product.id %} class="btn btn-info">View</a>
                        <button id={{product.id}} class="btn btn-warning atc">Add to Cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-4">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    {% if product_objects.has_previous %}
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{product_objects.previous_page_number}}">Prev</a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}

                    <li class="page-item active">
                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{product_objects.number}}">Current</a>
                    </li>


                    {% if product_objects.has_next %}
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="?page={{product_objects.next_page_number}}">Next</a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (localStorage.getItem('cart') == null) {
            var cart = {};
            document.getElementById('cart-link').innerHTML = "Cart (0)"
        }
        else {
            var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
            document.getElementById('cart-link').innerHTML = "Cart (" + Object.values(cart).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
                return accumulator + currentValue;
            }, 0) + ")"
        }
        $('.atc').on('click', (event) => {
            item_id = event.target.id.toString();
            if (cart[item_id] != undefined) {
                cart[item_id] += 1;
            }
            else {
                cart[item_id] = 1;
            }
            localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
            let nr_cart_items = Object.values(cart).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
                return accumulator + currentValue;
            }, 0);

            document.getElementById('cart-link').innerHTML = "Cart (" + nr_cart_items + ")"

            function displayCart(cart) {
                let cartString = "";
                cartString += "<h4>Your Cart</h4>";
                let index = 1
                for (let item in cart) {
                    cartString += index + document.getElementById('prod-name-' + item).innerHTML + " --> " + cart[item]
                    index += 1
                }
                document.getElementById("cart-link").setAttribute('data-bs-content', cartString);
            }
            displayCart(cart)
        });

        // popover code
        $(function () {
            $('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                html: true,
                title: '<h4>Your Cart</h4>',
                content: 'hello'
            });
        });




    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I am also getting this error when `displayCart` function runs.
[image]